# jQuery animate bumpy at start and end

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

This is my code (see fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/dLVWr/)):

```
$('div').on('click', function () {
    $('.well')
        .stop()
        .animate({
        height: "toggle",
        opacity: "toggle"
    });
});
```

I have a bootstrap `.well` with stuff below. Notice the discontinuity at the start and the end of the animation by looking at the stuff below.

How can I avoid these animation discontinuities?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check this out http://jsfiddle.net/dLVWr/1/:

**html:**

```
<div>Click to show/hide</div>
<div class='container'>
    <div class='well'>....</div>
</div>
<div>Stuff below</div>
```

**js:**

```
$('div').on('click', function () {
    $('.container')
        .stop()
        .animate({
        height: "toggle",
        opacity: "toggle"
    });
});
```

The problem with your code is that the `well` div has both text-height and padding. When toggling opacity and height, first, the content height is zeroes, that the padding. that's what makes that jump.

To avoid this make sure that the div you apply the `.animate` to has no margins/paddings.

Answer (score 1):

There's a small kick-in because you are animating the height of the content and disregarding the outer height of it.

This means that the `padding`, `border` and `margin` values will kick in once the element's `display` is toggled. That is, right after the animation is completed while hiding it or the animation has started when showing it.

You should use [`.slideToggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/) instead.

```
$('div').on('click', function () {
    $('.well').stop().animate();
});
```